# UITableView Detect Selected Cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, cell

I have multiple UITableViews in my app, is there a method of detecting which cell/row the user has selected in that column?

Also is it possible to programatically deselect a cell/row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Get currently selected index path for a table:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Deselect currently selected row:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

These are all easily found in the documentation for UITableView. Perhaps you should look there first next time.

Here's even a link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

The above line will throw **EXC BAD ACCESS** if no sell is selected so keep track of your selected cell with NSIndexPath instance variable and only **deselect** when it is actually selected with **isSelected** property of cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath];
if(cell.isSelected) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath animated:YES];
}
```