# Swift loop through all UITextViews from UITableView

Tags: swift

I generated a TableView with a list of items I fetch from an API. The result is that it shows me a TableView with a UILabel and UITextView.
The code works and gives me the wanted results:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:FormCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FormCell
        cell.formLabel.text = (self.fetchedData[indexPath.section] as! String)
// id is available = (self.fetchedDataID[indexPath.section] as! String)
        return cell
    }

    class FormCell: UITableViewCell {
        @IBOutlet weak var formLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var formAnswer: UITextView!
    }
```

But now I wanna submit the "answers" of all given formAnswer's in the UITextViews. How to achieve this?

The result I want to POST to an API is something like:

```
let params = [
    "id-of-": "theValueOfTheFormAnswer", // every Value of each UITextView 
] as [String : Any]

let requestURL = "/post-url"
let request = Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```

Comment: Before you worry about sending the values, you need to fix your table so it works properly as the user scrolls the table view. You have no code in `cellForRow` to set the text view text of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* try and retrieve all the text views from all the cells from the table view -- this will definitly never work, because cells (and all their subviews) might be reused, so data from a cell that is scrolled away from the screen will be lost forever.

Instead, you'll have to store the data each time a textview is modified (or loses focus or something) in your data model. Once the user finished, you'll just have to send the model's data to your backend.

Set a `UITextViewDelegate` delegate and update the model in one of the following methods:

- textViewDidEndEditing
- textViewDidChange

Comment: on which event?

Comment: You typically set a delegate and then implement your model update in some of the methods from the delegate's protocol

Comment: Don't set the delegate to the cell itself, and do not store any data from within the cell. The cell is a UI component, only meant to display data. Instead, set the delegate to the viewcontroller (to make things easy) from within the `cellForRow` call.

Comment: got it to work.  thnx. but textViewDidEndEditing  is triggered only when leaving the current textview of the cell. and textViewDidChange always, but that'll result in lots of request to backend. and how to get the indexpath of the filled in uitextview?

Comment: To geht the selected cell, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318386/uitableview-detect-selected-cell